# Create an entry for every method with APM.Net and ELK

Tags: .net, .net-core, elk, elastic-apm

I have a question to ask, about APM usage with .NET Core.
I have successfully set up AMP agent on .NET Core services, and log everything on ELK.

I have running traces on the APM section, showing on the timeline the controllers and the DB queries.

But I am wondering if it could be possible to also know in which methods it come across, in order to get metrics about each pieces of code it runs into ?

Here for example :
[image]

I miss some information between each db queries, and would like to know more about which piece of code and methods in run into.

If needed, I can share some of the code and configurations I have done.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Unfortunately this feature doesn't exist yet - this is an issue which would implement something like this: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-dotnet/issues/1761

What you can do is to look at the stack traces on the created spans, which may help. Here is the realted setting: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/config-stacktrace.html#config-span-stack-trace-min-duration

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i will do some tests with it.

So this post is considered as answered, thanks a lot